# Nginx does not response to port 80

Tags: http, nginx, webserver

I've just moved from a Debian to an Arch server but running in some problems. I'm running web applications on an nginx with the following config:

vhost: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46dec … cbdd439ccd
nginx.conf: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54f6d … b0ccbbe3f7

If I now try to enter http://2wickl.de in the browser (or CURL) I'll just get back strange binary data (%).
Only if I directly enter https://2wickl.de I'll get back the correct output (in this case https://www.2wickl.de). Even when I'm trying something like http://aasdflaksdflalsfdj.2wickl.de it does not work. If I try https://aasdflaksdflalsfdj.2wickl.de it works just as is should. I think, the nginx does not really get the chance to redirect or deliver the default site on port 80. Can anybody give me some hints, where I can have a look or did something wrong?

netstat -a -p -n|grep LISTEN delivers:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54d2d … 0111f1135d

Information: A firewall is running, but no rules are configured.

Thanks already for your help.
Regards
marove

Comment: the links with your configuration are returning 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation I found the problem:

One of my server-configurations had http2 enabled for http port 80

```
server {
    listen 80 http2;
    listen [::]:80 http2;
}
```

After changing to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

Everything works fine again. It is always a good advise to deactivate alle server-settings and turn on every server one by one.